# I can't return document.documentURI from my UIWebView injecting Javascript

Tags: javascript, swift

I don't know how to explain this very well but I'm stuck with this for hours, so I hope someone can help me figure this out.

This is my code in swift:

```
  let testjava = "var Hello = function(message) { return \"No problem\"; }"
  let testjava2 = "var Hello = function(message) { return document.documentURI; }"


  let context = JSContext()
  context?.evaluateScript(testjava2)
  let tagsFunc = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("Hello")
  let tags = tagsFunc?.call(withArguments: ["test"])
  print(tags)
```

When I try to run this with testjava the print result is "No problem" but if I try this code with testjava2 the print result is Undefined.

I'm using this code on a google image page inside a UIWebView

Could someone help me with this ? 
Thank you so much

Comment: Hi there- any reason why you’re not using WKWebView (that’s the class Apple recommends now); also, where are you calling this function? Are you sure the page has finished loading?

Comment: to emphasize @Sparky, use WKWebView, it is much easier to work with

Comment: Thank you both for your answer. I'm trying to switch from UIViewController to WKWebview and none of my Javascript work... All this function are called when I longpress on my screen so the page should be finish to load